Проблема с подсветкой текста в Vs Code
Недавно я узнал о сниппетах, и решил я создать себя сниппет для питона в Vs Code, но после вызова созданного сниппета подсвечивается текст, что делать?


Это потому-что сниппет имеет в определении for ${1:x} in ${2:range(10)}, текст подсвечивается там где его нужно менять. Если менять не нужно, то и окружать скобками не нужно. (PS) И вопрос следует задавать с полными данными определения сниппета.
